# How to set "Latha" font by default while writing docx file using poi jar

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to create a docx file using apache poi and in that i need to set its font to Latha. Below is my code but it is not working when i used setfontfamily("Latha"). Latha is a tamil font.

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(new File("PageCounter.docx"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WordDocCreation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText(replaceAll2);
        run.setFontFamily("Latha");
        run.setFontSize(10);
        document.write(out);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WordDocCreation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(WordDocCreation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Systen is writing the file but the unicode text is showing as boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in 3.7:
http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/NPE-setting-font-family-for-a-XWPFRun-td5050524.html

But is working in 3.8 (currently in Beta):
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52288

Comment: I Use the same version of poi jar 3.10 for poi and also use docj4 jar, i got the required output.

Comment: POI 3.8 was released over 3 years ago! The latest Apache POI release is 3.12, released in May 2015

Comment: For set the Tamil Font ,We must use the two methods. xssfFont.setFontName("Latha"); assertEquals("Latha",ctFont.getNameArray(0).getVal());run.setFontFamily("Latha")‌​; run.setText(replaceAll2); use the getCTR() method if u did not the required answer means.Then In Apache office its work will, some errors in Ms word